# How to cast a int to a specified personal object type?

Tags: python

I'm gonna print the elements of my list by below `printIt()` method. For final iteration by for loop, I need a casting stuff to change the index type `s` to my own class type `ord` so that the `printIt()` method could be used.

Does anybody have any idea for this case?

Thank you

```
class ord:
    def __init__(self, aString):
        self = aString

    def printIt(self):
        print(self.text)



s1 = ord("a")
s2 = ord("b")
note = [s1, s2]

for s in note:
    s.printIt() # something like s(type(ord), ord) which does not work!!!
```

**EDITED:** Here is the generated error:

```
'int' object has no attribute 'printIt'
```

Comment: Not clear what you are asking.  Since you put objects of `ord` class into the `note` list, you will get objects of `ord` class when you iterate with `for`.  No ints are involved here.  (`ord` is probably not the best choice for your class name, as there is a builtin function with that name.)

Comment: `self = aString` does nothing (did you mean `self.text = aString`?) and I have *no* idea what your title has to do with the rest of your question.

Comment: @BrenBarn: As you said, I have ord-driven objects in the list, but I am not still capable of this iteration. the printLn() function could be called by an ord object not an int index just like s.
I need an approach to handle this and change the type of s so that printIn() could be used.

Comment: @rioppi: You are right about the first point. As I said, I need to change the type of the index in for loop (s), to my own type (ord) in order to be able to use printIt() method

Comment: You can Cast Int using "int(self.text)"

Comment: @Mahesh24: That does not work...

Comment: Are you sure you are assigning to a `self.text` in your `__init__` instead of just `self`?

Comment: ord Is a built-in function, that returns an int.... Name your class something else

Comment: @Lafexlos: Yes... It is the thing it should be...

Comment: QJoran Beasley: Thank you!... I did worked!
Such a bad chance choosing the name of a built-in-function among all possible names!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rename your class to something else ... ord is a builtin, that you inadvertently shadow ...

```
class ordX:
    def __init__(self, aString):
        self.text = aString

    def printIt(self):
        print(self.text)



s1 = ordX("a")
s2 = ordX("b")
note = [s1, s2]

for s in note:
    s.printIt()
```

but further you should really just define str and repr for it

```
class ordX:
    def __init__(self, aString):
        self.text = aString    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
    def __repr__(self):
         return "<OrdX '%s'>"%self





s1 = ordX("a")
s2 = ordX("b")
note = [s1, s2]

for s in note:
    print(s)
    print(repr(s))
```

Comment: The utilization of str & repr sounds great, however renaming the class just hit the mark... Thank you!